# Apriori algorithm - selecting list of transactions

Tags: apriori

I'm attempting to infer errors occuring on a customer account using the apriori algorithm.  So I have an error table like so:

```
error_id    error_code    cust_id  
1           M015          100  
2           M020          101  
3           M016          100  
4           M019          100  
5           M015          102
```

...

And I want to establish what errors to expect given M015.
(e.g. M015 -> ??)

The problem is the error table contains hundreds of thousands of line items, and there are hundreds of possible error codes.  So do I run my algorithm with a really low confidence to get back as many possible rules as possible?  Or do I narrow down the errors database to only include "transactions" that include an error I'm interested in?

(In this example for instance, if I'm looking for rules M015, should I restrict the transactions table to only line items for cust_id 100 and 102?)

Answer (score 0):

For the minimum confidence and support thresholds, it is better to start with high values and then to lower them down if you did not get enough results.

But I think that you should keep the confidence high because otherwise the result will not be useful.  For example, maybe that you would like to have a confidence of at least 50 %.

Yes, for optimizations, you could modify the algorithm to only search for rules containing the item that you are interested. That would allow the algorithm to not generate a very large amount of rules.

But don't forget that an association is not a causal relationship. If you want to make some prediction according to time, you could use a "sequential rule mining algorithm" or sequential pattern mining algorithm" for example, instead of an association rule mining algorithm.